# CefSharp H.264 Support

Tags: cefsharp

Is there any easy way of implementing H.264 support in CefSharp WinForms? As I'm currently developing a wrapper around Apple Music Web for private usage and I would rather not go through the entire mess of building Cef etc.

**EDIT**: Ended up using WebView2 which has built-in H.264 support

Comment: You'd have to build CEF from source to enable h264.

Comment: You might be better off using the new web browser from Microsoft,  I'm told it has h264 support.